# Hibernate5 OneToMany and ManyToOne mapping giving null on foreign key

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys

Yet another thread like this. I fighting with this for 4 days.
annotation `@Getter` and `@Setter` are from lombok plugin

My `Place` class

```
@Entity
public class Place {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "place", targetEntity = Tag.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Tag> tags;
//...
}
```

`Tag` class which should be many

```
@Entity
public class Tag {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_place_id")
    private Place place;
//...
}
```

I'm saving it like this

```
 Tag tagOne = new Tag("tagOne");
 Tag tagTwo = new Tag("tagTwo");
 Set<Tag> tagSet = new HashSet<>();

 tagSet.add(tagOne);
 tagSet.add(tagTwo);
 Place place = new Place();
 place.setTags(tagSet);
 placeService.save(place);
```

[image: database after save]

saving looks is the single line `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(entity)` on every case. Saving entity with `@OneToOne` mapping it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bidirectional association. You're initializing only one side of the association, and that side is the inverse side (because it has the `mappedBy` attribute). Hibernate only cares about the owner side. So, for Hibernate, there is no association between the tags and the place.

Note that cascade=ALL on a ManyToXxx association doesn't make sense. If 100 tags are referencing the same place, and you delete one of these tags, you don't want to also delete the place. And even if you want to, that won't work, because 99 other tags still reference it, which will cause a referential integrity error.

Comment: Okey, so I added ` @JoinColumn(name = "fk_place_id")` to `Place` class and now `Place` class is the OWNER of this relation. My mistake was due that when I use `@JoinColumn` annotation it create column in entity where I used it. I viewed tons of tutorials and at some point I just stared copy-paste the code without thinkig.

Comment: You can't do that. In a bidirectional OneToMany, the Many side MUST be the owner. What you must do is `tagOne.setPlace(place); tagTwo.setPlace(place);`.

Comment: But it worked. So there is option to make it in other way?  Like this `place.setTags(tagsSet)`? If I have 100 tags I need loop to set place. I know that your solution is logical from database perspective, but I'm asking for other way to do that.

Comment: So, make a loop. What's the problem? Or make that loop in the `setTags()` method.

Comment: There is no problem, I just asking for make it in other way. Anyway thank you for your time and help. Now I can fall asleep peacefully :)

Comment: I had the exact same problem as above, JB Nizet you're right, i had to set the parent's object in the child to work. It's strange because as we're saving the parent, the idea is that the parent will be saved automagically in the child

Comment: Hi @JakubPomykała, I'm also facing the same issue, but sorry, i could not understand what was the exact solution for this. Can you please help.

Comment: `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "place") Set<Tag> tags;` and  `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "fk_place_id") Place place;` Now you need 1. persist tag using Hibernate, 2. persist place 3. persist tags 4. set tags to place 5. update place. `mappedBy` points to relation owner in this case it's place, so you need to `save` place with reference to tags and hibernate will setup foreign keys for you.

Comment: Thank you @JakubPomykała , This is working for me now but only if I use EntityManager.persist(tag) and EntityManager.persist(place) then but with hiberntae4 it was working with PlaceJparepository.save(place). Hibernate was itself taking care of tag and saving it. Why is it so with hibernate5  that i have save every object seperately?